# Using Loopback API for Authentication for other Loopback API

Tags: authentication, loopbackjs

It is possible to use loopback api as authenticate service for other loopback API?
For example I have:

1. SSO Service (Loopback API) with base Models: User, AccessToken,
   Role... to manage user by AccessToken from login method.
2. Product Service (Loopback API) with Persistent Model: Product to
   manage product, but request to this API must have AccessToken and
   will be authenticated by SSO Service.

I have tried using Loopback REST Connector to map User, AccessToken from SSO Service as Model tin Product Service, but still not find right solution to solve this requirement.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

We might create a middleware which would check the validity of the access_token received from product API by making a GET call from request npm to the exists api of accesstoken
i.e GET /accessTokens/id/exists

You could find details for the same in [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Access-token-REST-API.html)

But please note: you would have to allow the exists api first from the ACL